# I need to achieve this layout with css - fluid width div next to contained text div

Tags: html, css

Need to maintain fixed gap between the image and text.

How would one achieve this?

I have tried positioning both img and text absolute but with percentage widths set, the gap between the 2 would not remain constant. I figure this is a pretty common problem that comes up but can't seem to find anything else on stack-overflow or similar

[image]

Comment: Are the two text elements the same width/height as each other and are the two imgs the same width/height as each other always?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly.

Your elements need to be put in a container, you can use margin to set the gap between each elements.

In a flex container for example, you could use  `flex-grow:1` on the children to use all of the space and set the margin for your elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do it. This may work for you, because the content usually has some max width set:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
}
.strech {
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.text {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
.image {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.image img {
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-left: calc(100% - 50vw);
    display: block;
    width: calc(50vw - 20px);
}
.text + .image img {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: calc(100% - 50vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="strech">
        <div class="image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/100" /></div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        <div class="image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/250/100" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check it in full screen, or on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/92fmzreu/).

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use CSS grids for this. Hopefully, my code will be self-explanatory. But if you need an explanation let me know in reply, I'll edit the answer and write an explanation.

```css
.wrapper-column {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.inner-container:first-of-type {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
/*   Either use relative width or subtract fixed width */
/* width: calc(100% - 17rem);  */

  height: 5rem;
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.container-1 {
 
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
}

.container-2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.5fr;
}

.Item {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Img {
  background: #066BCB; 
}

.Text {
  background: #00CF62;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-column">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="container container-1">
      <div class="Item Img">Img</div>
      <div class="Item Text">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="container container-2">
      <div class="Item Text">Text</div>
      <div class="Item Img">Img</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```